# Go from windowed mode to fullscreen

Tags: c#, xna, window, fullscreen, xna-4.0

OK, what I want is code that will switch from windowed mode to fullscreen after my `gameState.gameLoading` so the next `gameState.mainMenu` state to be in is fullscreen. How do I do that? The code I have is: Variables:

```
    //Game States
    public enum gameState
    {
        gameLoading,
        mainMenu,
        gameOptions,
        levelSelect,
        gamePlaying,
        gameOver
    }
    gameState CurrentGameState = gameState.gameLoading;
```

`Update()` method:

```
        if (CurrentGameState != gameState.gameLoading)
        {
            IsMouseVisible = false;
            graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        }
        if (CurrentGameState == gameState.gameLoading)
        {
            IsMouseVisible = true;
            graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
        }
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: graphics.ToggleFullScreen() Note: don't work on XBOX

Comment: But when I place it in my `if()` methods I get exception. Please reply (didn't use thsi function before example would be great).

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: Look at this comment to see the exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382833/go-from-windowed-mode-to-fullscreen/#comment-27003108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is:

```
        //Update() method
        if (CurrentGameState == gameState.gameLoading)
        {
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
            {
                graphics.ToggleFullScreen(); //?
            }
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the graphics changes, like this:

```
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
// profit
```

Comment: After I get to fullscreen I get exception again: System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled "Cannot access a disposed object." on Program.cs line `Game.Run();` Also before you ask I never called the `Dispose()` method.

Comment: @PowerUser Does this only happen when you try to switch to fullscreen, or does it happen even if you don't? Maybe you tried to access `graphics.GraphicsDevice` before you called `base.Initialized()`?

Comment: Happens only when switching, `bse.Initialize();` is called in the `Initialize()` method.

Comment: @PowerUser Does it still crash when you switch to fullscreen *after* `base.Initialize()`?

Comment: Yes, it does crashes.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.togglefullscreen.aspx) you can check the exception you get using `graphics.ToggleFullScreen()` to fix it.